# Karnaugh map group sizes

Tags: karnaugh-map

Full disclosure, this is for an assignment I don't think I'm looking for spoon feeding, more so just a general question.  Am a I allowed to break that into a group of 8 and 2 groups of 4, or do all group sizes have to be equal, ie 4 groups of 4

1 0 1 1

0 0 0 0

1 1 1 1

1 1 1 1

Sorry if this is obvious, but my searches haven't been explicit and my teacher was quite vague. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR: Groups don't have to be equal in size.**

Let see what happens if, in your case, you take 11 groups of one. Then you will have an equation of eleven terms. (ie. `case_1 or case_2 or... case_11`).

By making big group, in your case 1 group of 8 and 2 groups of 4, you will have a very short and simplified equation like: `case_group_8 or case_group_4_1 or case_group_4_2`.

Both grouping are correct (we took all the one in the map) but the second is the most optimized. (i.e. you cannot simplified more)

Making 4 groups of 4 will bring you an equation that can be simplified more.

The best way now is for you to try both grouping (all 4 vs 8/4/4) and see the output result.